# How to mock and setup MudBlazor.IDialogService - dialogresult using Moq?

Tags: .net, moq, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor, bunit

I am writing unit test for blazor webAssembly using Bunit, Xunit and Moq.

I want to mock MudBlazor.IDialogService

test file

```
var mockDialogService = new Mock<IDialogService>();

var ctx = new Bunit.TestContext();
           ctx.Services.AddScoped<IDialogService, DialogService>();

var cut = new Participant(
           mockDialogService.Object
);
```

in .razor method

```
var parameters = new DialogParameters();
parameters.Add("ContentText", "Please assign coordinator before schedule a meeting.");
parameters.Add("ButtonText", "Ok");
parameters.Add("Color", Color.Primary);

var options = new DialogOptions() { MaxWidth = MaxWidth.Medium };

var dialogresult = DialogService.Show<ConfirmationDialog>("Warning", parameters, options);  
// when debugging in test mode dialogresult is null how can I setup this?

var result = await dialogresult.Result;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to mock the `IDialogReference` that represents your dialog:

```
var confirmationDialogReference = new Mock<IDialogReference>();
confirmationDialogReference.SetupGet(x => x.Result).Returns(Task.FromResult(DialogResult.Ok<object>(new object())));

var mockDialogService = new Mock<IDialogService>();
mockDialogService.Setup(x => x.ShowAsync<ConfirmationDialog>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<DialogParameters>(), It.IsAny<DialogOptions>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(confirmationDialogReference.Object);
```

And then add the mocked service to the DI container:

```
ctx.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IDialogService), mockDialogService.Object);
```